# Operator $ne/$not in MongoDb query?

Tags: mongodb

I tried to build selector for `find()`:

```
$selector = array("type" => array('$not' => array("2", "3")));
```

That to get all rows where "type" is not **2** and **3**.

But it does not work...

Document example is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59218620470e6cb90e3c9878"),
    "name" : "Acceleration",
    "default" : "2",
    "visibility" : "1",
    "type" : NumberLong(1),
    "only_numbers" : null,
    "value" : "2",
    "available" : "1"
}
```

Comment: You mean [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) I think. Which actually means cannot contain either "2" **or** "3". Hard to tell without showing some documents in your question.

Comment: I added document in question

Comment: Yep. You want `$nin`. Note that the field is "numeric" where your code attempt was using "strings", so change that. Read the documentation. That's why I supplied the link.

Comment: Do you mean this: `$selector = array("type" => array('$nin' => array("2", "3")));`?

Comment: Numeric `$selector = array("type" => array('$nin' => array(2, 3)));`